# Declaring an array (visual c++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to c# and I encountered some errors. I tried looking for answers and tutorials and such, but they're not working for me. Here is the troubling code:

```
    panou_medii->Visible = true ;
    public: static int[] elem = new int[10] ;
```

And this is the error: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'public'.
Without the public static in front, I get 4 errors and a warning.
PS. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and working on a form.

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion everyone, it was a visual c++ windows form, not a c#

Comment: The posted code is not C#. Are you sure you're working in a C# project?

Comment: @Bea Welcome to Stackoverflow, can you tell us what kind of project you have created?

Comment: To be honest, I started working on a Windows Form yesterday and the tutorials from C# are working.

Answer (score 5):

Thats because the code is not correct C# syntax, I think you want:

```
panou_medii.Visible = true;

public static int[] elem = new int[10];
```

Comment: It's only generating more errors

Comment: @Bea I think you're haven't created a C# Windows Forms project. But a other one. Probably C or C++

Comment: I checked again and you are right, it was a visual c++ windows form. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

There is one obvious mistake in the code you show, and probably a second one, depending on what you are really doing.

The easy one is in the line

```
public: static int[] elem = new int[10] ;
```

In C# access modifiers (like `public`, `private`, `protected` etc.) are *not* followed by a colon (`:`), so the correct syntax is

```
public static int[] elem = new int[10];
```

---

But your first line:

```
panou_medii->Visible = true ;
```

Here you use a [dereferencing/member access operator (`->`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8bz4d5h.aspx). This operator can only be used with *pointers* in an *`unsafe`* context.
This is not very common in C#, and since you said you are working on a form, I guess it's not what you intended.

To access properties of a class instance in C#, we use the [`.` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zhxzbds.aspx). `Visible` in your example is probably a property of a `Control` and `panou_medii` is an instance of that `Control` (or precisely a variable containing a reference of that instance).

So to access the `Visible` of set instance use

```
panou_medii.Visible = true;
```

---

If you are getting more errors now, you will need to show some more of your code. For a start: if the two lines you showed are following each other directly, there's definitly something wrong. The first line is a *statement* that can only exist *inside* a method. The second line is a *member declaration* that cannot be contained in a method. (If you declare a *variable* inside a method, you don't use access modifiers like `public`).